# All expressions from one page

Tags: python, parsing

I have this code to retrieve information from a page:

```
def between_strings(source, start='<a href="http://site.com/', end='class'):
    words = []
    while True:
        start_index = source.find(start)
        if start_index == -1:
            break
        end_index = source.find(end)
        words.append(source[start_index+len(start):end_index])
        source = source[end_index+len(end):]
    return words

stat = between_strings(page)
```

I want to get all the values ​​from the page, but this code returns only the first.

Comment: Without having your input, it's pretty hard to know what's wrong.  Also, parsing html tags by hoping that there is a `class` attribute which comes directly after `href` strikes me as a particularly fragile method.

Comment: Sorry, my code get's all values. Close it

Comment: You can delete your post yourself, just hit 'delete'.

Comment: btw, you should use the optional `start` argument to the `find` method instead of creating a new `source` string  in every iteration of the loop